# Can't render two charts on the same page from chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've been trying for the past hour to get Chart.js to render two line charts on the same page.
I have ensured that my canvas element IDs are unique, as are my variables.

I am able to successfully load the first chart, `ctx` or `canvas`, but not the second chart, `ctx2` or `canvas2`.

This is using chart.js v2.8.0

[Here's the log of errors from inspect element.](https://pastebin.com/yp7Cb8Yu)

***Input Data*** defined in `index.html`

```js
var lineChartData = {
        labels: ['-18:00', '-15:00', '-12:00', '-9:00', '-6:00', '-3:00', '0:00'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Temperature (F)',
            borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
            fill: false,
            data: [
                60 - randomScalingFactor(),
                55 - randomScalingFactor(),
                57 - randomScalingFactor(),
                58 - randomScalingFactor(),
                59 - randomScalingFactor(),
                65 - randomScalingFactor(),
                73 - randomScalingFactor()
            ],
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
        }]
    };

    var avgLineChartData = {
        labels: ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Avg Temperature (F)',
            borderColor: window.chartColors.green,
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green,
            fill: false,
            data: [
                65 - randomScalingFactor(),
                53 - randomScalingFactor(),
                58 - randomScalingFactor(),
                54 - randomScalingFactor(),
                62 - randomScalingFactor(),
                65 - randomScalingFactor(),
                74 - randomScalingFactor()
            ],
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
        }]
    };
```

***Chart Drawing*** in `index.html`

```js
window.onload = function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: lineChartData,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                hoverMode: 'index',
                stacked: false,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Temp(F)/Humidity(%) per 15 Hours'
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                        display: true,
                        position: 'left',
                        id: 'y-axis-1',
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            max: 100,
                        },
                    }, {
                        type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                        display: true,
                        position: 'right',
                        id: 'y-axis-2',
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            max: 100,
                        },
                        // grid line settings
                        gridLines: {
                            drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
                        },
                    }],
                },
                elements: {
                    line: {
                        tension: 0.3
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        var ctx2 = document.getElementById('canvas2').getContext('2d');
        new Chart(ctx2, {
            type: 'line',
            data: avgLineChartData,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                hoverMode: 'index',
                stacked: false,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Avg Temp(F)/Humidity(%) per 7 Days'
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                        display: true,
                        position: 'left',
                        id: 'avg-y-axis-1',
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            max: 100,
                        },
                    }, {
                        type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                        display: true,
                        position: 'right',
                        id: 'avg-y-axis-2',
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            max: 100,
                        },
                        // grid line settings
                        gridLines: {
                            drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
                        },
                    }],
                },
                elements: {
                    line: {
                        tension: 0.3
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

***Canvas elements*** defined in `index.html`

```html
<div class="container">
     <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
     <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you data,

```
var avgLineChartData = {
        labels: ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Avg Temperature (F)',
            borderColor: window.chartColors.green,
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green,
            fill: false,
            data: [
                65 - randomScalingFactor(),
                53 - randomScalingFactor(),
                58 - randomScalingFactor(),
                54 - randomScalingFactor(),
                62 - randomScalingFactor(),
                65 - randomScalingFactor(),
                74 - randomScalingFactor()
            ],
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
        }]
    };
```

you set the `yAxisId : 'y-axis-1'`. but when you draw the chart, they are `id: 'avg-y-axis-1'`.